# Clojure: convert an arbitrary list into string representation, hopefully lazily?

Tags: clojure

I'm tired of writing a lots code to print out list structure, based on the structure of the list. For example, for

`'(1 2 3)`, I'll

`(apply str '(1 2 3))`
but for

`'((1 2 3) (4 5 ))`, I should

`(map #(apply str %) '((1 2 3) (4 5 )))`

and so on depending upon the nesting structure of the list.

I wonder what would be an elegant function to-string to deal with arbitrary list structure?

Below is a sketch, hoping to learn better solution.

```
(defun to-string
"convert argument into string."
([x & xs] (str (to-string x) (to-string xs) "\n"))
([x] (str x))
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that if you quote inside another quote, the second `'` will expand to `quote` and not be evaluated. You probably only want one `'` around the whole expression.

Comment: @Alex, thanks pointing outthe mistake of using ' inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pprint` will print nicely formatted data structures:

```
user=> (clojure.pprint/pprint '('(1 2 3) '(4 5 )))
('(1 2 3) '(4 5))
```

You can use `with-out-str` to bind `*out*` to send the output of `pprint` to a string rather than `stdout`:

```
(def s 
  (with-out-str 
     (clojure.pprint/pprint '('(1 2 3) '(4 5 )))))
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to get some consistent yet fully controlled way to format any data, you could employ the `cl-format` function from `clojure.pprint`. It is the port of the common lisp's awesome `format` function. So for example for example:

```
user> (require '[clojure.pprint :refer [cl-format]])
nil

user> (cl-format nil "~{~a~}" '(1 2 3 4))
"1234"

user> (cl-format nil "~{~{~a~}~^ ~}" '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)))
"12 34 56"
```

and so on. There is a nice tutorial here: http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html and more info in [clhs](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/22_c.htm)

you can go further, for example, and make some format generating function (or macro):

```
user> (defmacro make-fstring [level]
        (nth (iterate #(str "~{" % "~^ ~}") "~{~a~}") (dec level)))
#'user/make-fstring

user> (cl-format nil (make-fstring 2) '((1 2 3) (4 5 6)))
"123 456"

user> (cl-format nil (make-fstring 3) '(((1 2) (3 4) (5 6) (7 8)) 
                                        ((9 10) (11 12))))
"12 34 56 78 910 1112"
```